# Need to Fix Broken Edge Loop?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, extrude

I'm trying to create a nightstand that has these inset circular handles. See below:

[image]

[image]

However on the bottom drawer handle, the edge loop of the circle is broken in two halves so I can't use the extrude/inset face tool to create the same look as the top one. See what I mean here:

[image]

I've tried to Merge Vertices, I've tried to Connect Vertices, I've tried Make Edge/Face. Usually I can just bungle my way through something stupid like this but I'm stuck and can't seem to google it either everyone's situation seems different. Which makes me think I'm missing something really dumb and simple. My brain doesn't seem to work with simple I over complicate. Anyway any ideas? Much appreciated in advance thanks.

[Editing to add my .blend file.](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50689)

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment to make it simpler: any chance you can upload the file? Broken loops are usually easy to work with if you select both. And can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do? I'm a little confused X_X

Comment: Hi I just edited my original post with a link to some .blend file uploader I hope it works. Worked for me. Basically I want to select that edge loop and then extrude inwards to create two concentric circles so the handle has like a border. The pictures should explain though the quality is not great when zoomed in. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ugh I think I just figured it out. I selected both halves of the circle's edge, then used Edge Split from the mesh menu which seemed to make it into a whole loop again and not just two halves. However I still wasn't able to inset inward. So then I selected the edge loop and did Make Edge/Face and it seemed to work. Just wanted to post this in case anyone else came across. Would also like to hear what you think Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, Sub-D approach: absolutely no better than yours, but with all the tools in Blender that are geared to working this way, personally I find this kind of pattern  gives rise  to fewer mysterious faults in the mesh, and is easier to tweak later.

[image]

Starting with a bevelled pair of drawers:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  Cut in 3 edge-loops in both directions
- <kbd>F</kbd> Fill the central faces
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> Poke the filled faces
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the central vertices
- Select both resulting faces, and Loop-Tools > Circle, ( or Space-Bar > Circle) setting the Radius field as desired.
- Inset <kbd>I</kbd> and Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> the circular faces, to create holding loops and the recess.
- Assign a Subdivision Surface modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This will break your loop on the outside, but it shouldn't make any difference (you'll just have to manually select the ring parts). Unlike the edge split modifier which affects your whole mesh, it won't duplicate anything. This is the easiest way that I found, and I'll write this as the answer as it seems most efficient. It has to do with another setting that you perhaps had on as a default. By the way, the reason why your **top** loop was working but not the bottom has to do with having two edges on top of each other. This method (the solution I'm giving to you) duplicates the edges in the same way. You can test this fact by taking one of the long edges on the face of the drawer (top and bottom for comparison) and re-sizing it. You'll see that it pulls away from the inset circles, leaving another edge loop behind it.

Here are the steps to replicate that:

1. Disable the proportional editing where the magnet icon is (left of it).
2. Select both sides of the loop.
3. Extrude them by nothing (doubles the edges).
4. Re-size.

Refer to this gif:

[image]

Comment: Hi all it's been a while here I went on in a different direction with this and decided to do the handles as separate objects rather than extruded out of the cube. I wanted to do beveling etc. and it just made more sense. Thank you for taking the time to respond much appreciated.

Comment: Sure thing. Since it is a stylistic issue/recommendation, the answer may not touch on such--just touch on what you're trying to do in the current situation.